# CSS Sticky Left does not stick past the body

Tags: css, html, sticky

I am working on a page where I am trying to, in Excel terms, freeze the Left column. When the user scrolls to the right, the leftcolumn needs to remain visible. The entire page is using divs, not tables. I'm freezing the left most divs using css:

```
.sticky-test {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
}
```

It seems to work up when I scroll to a certain point. but eventfully disappear, The contents extend many inches off the screen. The sticky divs seem to disappear once I move past the original body contents.

Is there a solution to keep it sticky?

Here is some of the html:

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-row nact-row">
<input type="hidden" class="nact-form-control" id="z0__LastName" name="[0].LastName" value="FNAME" />
<input type="hidden" class="nact-form-control" id="z0__FirstName" name="[0].FirstName" value="LNAME" />
<input type="hidden" class="nact-form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The NPI # Type 1 field is required." id="z0__NpiNumberType1" name="[0].NpiNumberType1" value="1225195811" />
<input type="hidden" class="nact-form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Service Provider Id field is required." id="z0__ServiceProviderId" name="[0].ServiceProviderId" value="395" />

<div class="nact-tbl-display-long sticky-test nact-status-new">FNAME, LNAME</div>

<div class="nact-tbl-display">1225195811</div>
.
. 
.
</div>
```

Here is what is happening. The fname, lname is sticky. If I keep scrolling over just a bit more (past the original body), it will disappear
[image: My site]

Comment: can you add more code? html + css

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. But are you sure you don't need `fixed` rather than `sticky`? The behaviour you describe is by design: a `sticky` block is only sticky as long as its container is visible on the screen; the idea being that it's no longer needed when outside its defined environment.